# Как покрасить всю кнопку в оранжевый цвет

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  background-color:black;
}
.Rectangle-2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 301px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #ff7043;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.open-shop {
  width: 221px;
  height: 14px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.5;
  letter-spacing: -0.6px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="Rectangle-2"><span class="open-shop">Жырный</span></button>
```

Не могу покрасить всю кнопку в оранжевый цвет, как видите, сверху есть полоса белого цвета. Как я могу ее покрасить? Чтобы вся кнопка была оранжевой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

по умолчанию у кнопу есть бордер, а еще надо убрать при фокусе outline, что бы прилично выглядел, забыл сразу отметить сей факт

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.Rectangle-2 {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 301px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #ff7043;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border: none;
}

.Rectangle-2:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.open-shop {
  width: 221px;
  height: 14px;
  font-family: ProximaNova;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 0.5;
  letter-spacing: -0.6px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="Rectangle-2"><span class="open-shop">Жырный</span></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Это `border` 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Два варианта решения:
  1) удалить border - `border: none;`
  2) заменить на другие стили - `border: 2px solid #ff7043;`

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

.Rectangle-2 {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 301px;
    height: 60px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    background-color: #ff7043;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border: 2px solid #ff7043;
}

.open-shop {
    width: 221px;
    height: 14px;
    font-family: ProximaNova;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 0.5;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<button class="Rectangle-2"><span class="open-shop">Жырный</span></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте свойство **border-color** или попробовать так можно

```
border: 1px solid #ff7043
```

Comment: Спасибо вам через 8 минут приму ваш ответ как правильный .